# How do I add to a table and then use the id for another query?

Tags: postgresql, insert

I have three tables, which I create with these queries:

```
create table parents(
    rowid serial primary key,
    display_name varchar,
    unique(display_name)
);

create table clients(
    rowid serial primary key,
    parent int,
    display_name varchar,
    foreign key (parent) references parents(rowid),
    unique(display_name, parent)
);

create table datapoints(
    rowid serial primary key,
    client int,
    val float8,
    foreign key (client) references clients(rowid)
);
```

I am getting data which contains parent name, client name and some value. Each time I get this data, I want to add rows to the datapoints table. I also want to add rows to the clients and parents table, but only if the data I received has unrecognized names.

For example, I might get this data:

"parent1-client1-123.0"

What I would like to achieve is to process this data (in a query), this way:

Insert a row to the "parents" table, if needed.

Insert a row to the "clients" table with the appropriate parent id (obtained in the previous step?), if needed.

Insert a row to the "datapoints" table with the appropriate client id (obtained in the previous step?).

How can I manage this with queries? The programmer in me wants to write:

- Insert into parents if needed. Save the id of appropriate parent in a variable "current_parent"
- Insert into clients if needed, using the "current_parent" variable. Save the id of the appropriate client in a variable "current_client".
- Insert into datapoints, using the "current_client" variable from the prev. step.

But obviously this is not how sql works, right? And what if, instead of these three "nested" tables I have 5, or 10?(!)

Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a trivial application of `INSERT ... RETURNING`:

```
INSERT INTO parents (display_name)
VALUES ('papa')
RETURNING rowid;
```

Then you can use the returned value for the next `INSERT`.

You can do all three inserts in a single SQL statement using CTEs:

```
WITH p_ids AS (
   INSERT INTO parents (display_name)
   VALUES ('papa')
   RETURNING rowid
), c_ids AS (
   INSERT INTO clients (parent, display_name)
   SELECT p_ids.rowid, 'murcielago'
   FROM p_ids
   RETURNING rowid
)
INSERT INTO datapoints (client, val)
SELECT c_ids.rowid, 2.71828
FROM c_ids;
```

Comment: Thank you! Can I combine it with a "only insert if not exists" type of logic?

Comment: Run three `INSERT INTO ... ON CONFLICT`. But I won't spoon-feed you.